# Opening a div (like popup) after click of button using HTML /CSS /Angular 6 Animation

Tags: html, css, angular6

I'm developing a small chat application using angular 6. When more than 3 chat boxes are opened I have to hide it and need to show when the user clicks on a button. Exactly like Facebook.

[image]

I have already design a button. But need to add popup with exceeded chat boxes. I can use HTML, CSS or angular 6.

I can do the angular part. I just don't know how to add that popup top of the button like Facebook with CSS.

[image]

```css
button.toggle {
    float: left;position: relative;height: 39px; 
    width: 39px;background-color: #f7eaea;border: 1px solid #abd2de;
}
```

```html
 <button class="toggle">
    <img alt="messages" class="messagesIcon" src="https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yA/r/r0HGsdgqAb2.png"  style="height:20;width:20;border: 0;">
  
  </button>
```

Comment: `slice` your array so the for can only output 3 of them, then do an if `.length` > n on the image you want to show if there is more than 3

Comment: This looks more like an upload button

Comment: @MatthiasSeifert LoL,I can change icon any time and can do the angular part.I just don't know how to add that popup top of the button like facebook with CSS.

Comment: @PaulJohnDiwa I just need to know how to set styles looks like facebook popup with the click event.